# Is there a function of time-limit for delete own posts in Mattermost?

Tags: admin, mattermost

I need to setup time-limit for deleting posts for users in Mattermost. It is in the editing posts, but i couldn't find it for delete own posts. How can I reach this? Also how to setup deleting posts with attachements (pictures etc)?

I couldn't find this in the system-console, as well as in the documentation of Mattermost